# How to create prefetched data to save in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am new to IOS i need to know how to create prefetched data to save in tableview.New entry data to be saved successfully.Prefetched data stored in array[currarray] that data how to save in tableview using core data.

Coding for save method:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Create a new managed object
    NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    //[newDevice setValue:self.amountTxt.text forKey:@"amount"];
    [newDevice setValue:self.nameTextFeild.text forKey:@"name"];
    [newDevice setValue:self.companyTextFeild.text forKey:@"company"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];}
```

coding for tableview:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.namelbl.text = [device valueForKey:@"name"];
    cell.companylbl.text = [device valueForKey:@"company"];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What did you write for fetching data from database?

Comment: My data in  array format using post method  that data i want to save @JigarTarsariya